# how to convert this Associative array into another form in PHP?

Tags: php, arrays, associative-array

hey I'm using PHP and I have this array called $memdeps

```
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [rel_id] => 2
                    [dep_id] => 4
                    [member_id] => 8
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [rel_id] => 3
                    [dep_id] => 1
                    [member_id] => 8
                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [rel_id] => 4
                    [dep_id] => 3
                    [member_id] => 8
                )

            [3] => Array
                (
                    [rel_id] => 9
                    [dep_id] => 3
                    [member_id] => 9
                )

            [4] => Array
                (
                    [rel_id] => 8
                    [dep_id] => 1
                    [member_id] => 9
                )

        )
```

and I want to convert it to a form where the dep_id key contains all the related member_id's

the wanted result is like that form

```
[dep_id] => Array
                (
                    [0] => member_id 1
                    [1] => member_id 2
                    [2] => member_id 3
                )
```

and the actually wanted result is like that

```
[0] => Array
         (
            [3] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 8
                    [1] => 9
                )
            [4] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 8
                )
           [1] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 8
                    [1] => 9
                )
       )
```

I tried that code

```
$memdep = array();
foreach($memdeps as $key => $value){
    $memdep[] = $memdep[][$value->dep_id] = $value->member_id;
}
```

and it's not working , and I don't know how to be able to do it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the solution

```
$memdep = array();

foreach($memdeps as $key => $value)

{

$memdep[$value->dep_id][] = $value->member_id;

}
```

Comment: the result is Array
(
    [$value->dep_id] => 9
)

Comment: Added both versions please check now.

Comment: Check now. I tested the 1st non-multi one and it works.

Comment: After final edits now both are multi. Edited the post to reflect that.